# Spark sql groupby and concat

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following table

```
REF    SEQ   DATA
---------------------
1       5      a
1       1      b
1       9      c

2       12      d
2       3      e
2       8      f
```

And i want to get following result.

```
REF     DATA
---------------------
1        bac
2        efd
```

How can i do it spark sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupBy`, `collect_list` & `concat_ws` function.

Check below code.

```
df
.orderBy($"SEQ".asc)
.groupBy($"REF")
.agg(collect_list($"DATA").as("DATA"))
.select($"REF",concat_ws("",$"DATA").as("DATA"))
.show(false)

+---+----+
|REF|DATA|
+---+----+
|1  |bac |
|2  |efd |
+---+----+
```

SQL

```
scala> spark.sql("with data as (select * from tbl order by seq asc) select REF,concat_ws('',collect_list(DATA)) AS DATA from data group by REF")
.show(false)

+---+----+
|REF|DATA|
+---+----+
|1  |bac |
|2  |efd |
+---+----+
```

Comment: Order is not preventing...even when user order by. also do u have raw sql for this?

Comment: Raw sql is ok,except if SEQ is underored,it is concating in wrong order.. maybe windows fucntion should be used to fix it?

Comment: I updated the question.. and expected result can u check please ?

Comment: it works,but if i use join,it shuffles again