# spark create multiple rows from columns which is array of element

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following data

```
+-----------+--------+
|A          | B      |
+-----------+--------+
|[ddd, ddd1]|[22, 33]|
+-----------+--------+
```

how can I turn it into following using spark sql

```
+-----------+--------+
|A          |BB     |
+-----------+--------+
|ddd        |22      |
|ddd1       |33
+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explode a map constructed using `map_from_arrays`:

```
spark.sql("select explode(map_from_arrays(A,B)) as (A, BB) from df").show()
+----+---+
|   A| BB|
+----+---+
| ddd| 22|
|ddd1| 33|
+----+---+
```

Comment: if you have 3 columns instead of 2 columns map_from_arrays is not working.. any idea?

Comment: in that case use `spark.sql("select inline(arrays_zip(A,B,C)) from df")`

Comment: super thx.. last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896978/spark-sql-groupby-and-concat/67897526#67897526